# Sending JPEG blob to S3: The stored file is the complete multipart request instead the JPEG

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, upload, blob, jpeg

My software enables to "retouch" images and then sends the resulting canvas to S3 bucket from Browser as a jpeg image.

First of all, I obtain the Image Blob using [https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob][1].

```
myCanvas.toBlob(function(blob){
  uploadFile("myImage.jpg", blob).then(function(){
    $log.log("upload finished");
  });
},"image/jpeg",90);
```

Upload is performed in 2 fases: sign the S3 reques with my Application server and then upload to the S3 bucket (using angular file upload [https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload][1])

```
var uploadFile = function(fileName, blob){
  return signRequest(fileName).
    then(function(s3SignData){
      return $upload.upload({
        url: s3SignData.url,
        method: 'PUT',
        data: s3SignData.credentials,
        headers: {"x-amz-acl":s3SignData.credentials.acl},
        file: blob,
        fileName: fileName
      });

    });
  };
```

After upload, I can find the file in the  S3 bucket but, surprise, when I download the file **I haven't a JPEG:  I have the multipart sended request**:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryBrzMD5YylSAtfLid
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0wNC0wMVQxMjowMDowMC4wMDBaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W3siYnVja2V0IjoiZDRsIn0sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRrZXkiLCJmb2xkZXJzLzU1L2FhM2I3MmYxNjY3ZGM5OGEwOGI2YzVlNTk5Nzk5MTcyLzAwMDAwMF9MYW5kc2NhcGVfN19qcGcuanBnIl0seyJhY2wiOiJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LFsiY29udGVudC1sZW5ndGgtcmFuZ2UiLDAsMjA5NzE1MjBdLFsiZXEiLCIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwiaW1hZ2UvanBlZyJdXX0=
------WebKitFormBoundaryBrzMD5YylSAtfLid
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

RHmScYS9OIR/WkNoqBE9kZn6cJQ=
------WebKitFormBoundaryBrzMD5YylSAtfLid
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

ZKSAJQFCLBSJEQJR6ZTQ
------WebKitFormBoundaryBrzMD5YylSAtfLid
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

public-read
------WebKitFormBoundaryBrzMD5YylSAtfLid
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

aa3b/72f1667dc98a08b6c5e599799172/000000_Landscape_7_jpg.jpg
------WebKitFormBoundaryBrzMD5YylSAtfLid
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="expires"

2015-04-01T12:00:00.000Z
------WebKitFormBoundaryBrzMD5YylSAtfLid
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content-type"

image/jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryBrzMD5YylSAtfLid
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="000000_Landscape_7_jpg.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿ........
Here all the file content 
.....
------WebKitFormBoundaryBrzMD5YylSAtfLid--
```

Comment: To do a form `POST` upload... you use `POST` ... not `PUT`... http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As michael-sqlbot mentioned, **I have to use POST**

Additionally, **URL must be the bucket URL, not the key one**:  the parameter key is used to know where to place the file into the bucket.

The example code:

```
var uploadFile = function(fileName, blob){
  return signRequest(fileName).
    then(function(s3SignData){
      return $upload.upload({
        url: s3SignData.postURL,
        method: 'POST',
        data: s3SignData.postData,
        file: blob,
        fileName: fileName
      });

    });
  };
```

Where :

- *s3SignData.postURL* === "*mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com*"
- *s3SignData.postData* contains all post params: *"policy", "signature", "AWSAccessKeyId", "acl", "key", "content-type"*